# Sorting a list using an alphabet string

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list containing only lower case letters by using the string :

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".
```

that is without using sort, and with O(n) complexity only. 
I got here:

```
def sort_char_list(lst):
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
new_list = []
length = len(lst)

for i in range(length):
    new_list.insert(alphabet.index(lst[i]),lst[i])
    print (new_list)

return new_list
```

for this input :

```
m = list("emabrgtjh")
```

I get this:

```
['e']
['e', 'm']
['a', 'e', 'm']
['a', 'b', 'e', 'm']
['a', 'b', 'e', 'm', 'r']
['a', 'b', 'e', 'm', 'r', 'g']
['a', 'b', 'e', 'm', 'r', 'g', 't']
['a', 'b', 'e', 'm', 'r', 'g', 't', 'j']
['a', 'b', 'e', 'm', 'r', 'g', 't', 'h', 'j']
['a', 'b', 'e', 'm', 'r', 'g', 't', 'h', 'j']
```

looks like something goes wrong along the way, and I can't seem to understand why.. if anyone can please enlighten me that would be great.

Comment: You're inserting into your `new_list` at the index of your `alphabet` string... this won't sort your list.

Comment: Its not O(n) if you have to search the list each iteration (which is what `index` has to do).

Comment: why not? it looks like it's working until i=6. I would be glad if you can explain more (:

Comment: Try opening a python shell and writing: `x = []`, then `x.insert(42, "foo")`. You won't see "foo" in the 42nd entry of `x`, you'll see something else...

Comment: Does this need to handle duplicates?

Comment: it looks like you are looking for a bucket sort. you need to create 26 buckets, then you need to find the bucket in o(1) (you are doing o(26) because that is the complexity of your reference string, that can count as o(1), but there are better ways.), then you need to join your buckets

Comment: @ScottHunter: no. the `lst` has a fixed known size, so the `lst.index` operation is considered o(1) (although something based on `ord` would be much more efficient)

Comment: it does need to handle duplicates, and I can't use ord() or chr()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a bucket sort. Here:

```
def sort_char_list(lst):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    # Here, create the 26 buckets
    new_list = [''] * len(alphabet)

    for letter in lst:
        # This is the bucket index
        # You could use `ord(letter) - ord('a')` in this specific case, but it is not mandatory
        index = alphabet.index(letter)
        new_list[index] += letter

    # Assemble the buckets
    return ''.join(new_list)
```

As for complexity, since `alphabet` is a pre-defined fixed-size string, searching a letter in it is requires at most 26 operations, which qualifies as `O(1)`. The overall complexity is therefore `O(n)`

Comment: thank you so much, I'm so glad to learn new things and methods to deal with problems. I'm still very new to this, it is great this community exists to share great peoples' ideas. thanks again !